# Haskell Error - Naked Expression at Top Level

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have the following code:

```
fib n
    | n == 0  = 0
    | n == 1  = 1
    | n > 1  = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)

print fib 5
```

And for some reason, it's throwing an error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, test.o )

test.hs:8:1: Parse error: naked expression at top level
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You cannot have an expression at the top-level. Haskell program entry point is a `main` function in `Main` module. Also `print fib 5` calls `print` with two arguments, you need to do:

```
main = print $ fib 5
```

or

```
main = print (fib 5)
```

Comment: When I run `ghc test.hs` it compiles...and then does nothing. What do I do to run it?

Comment: @tekk It should create an executable -- not sure what the default name is, but `ls` should tell you. Or you can just do `runhaskell test.hs` and it will run it right "from the source".

Comment: @qed http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io.html or http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#hello-world or whatever. Keyword is IO monad.